# Python - Remove one letter in a string

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to delete a variable (which is a string) from a list of strings. So basically:

```
list = ["A", "G", "T", "C"]
number = 2
newlist = ["A", "G", "T", "C"] - list[number]
```

This should then give:

```
newlist = ["A", "G", "C"]
```

But when I try this it gives me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mini.py", line 3, in <module>
    newlist = ["A", "G", "T", "C"] - list[number]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'str'
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `["A", "G", "T", "C"].remove(list[number])` ?

Comment: Or `list.pop(number)`. It's unclear why you thought list subtraction would work. Also, don't use `list` as an identifier for your own lists, it shadows the built-in.

Comment: `list` is one of the reserved words in Python. It's better not to use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

There are a several of ways to do what you want.

If you want to modify the starting list (rather than creating a new one), you could use a `del` statement to remove the desired index:

```
del oldlist[index]
```

If you need a reference to the value you're removing (and don't have it already), you can call `pop` on the list instead:

```
value_removed = oldlist.pop(index)
```

If you want to keep the old list as it was though, you need to copy the list's data in order to be able to remove the value without changing the original list. One way to do that is simply to copy the entire list, then use `del` on the index in the copy:

```
newlist = oldlist.copy() # or list(oldlist) or oldlist[:]
del newlist[index]
```

Another option is to use slicing to get the part of the list before the index, and the part after the index, then concatenate them together. That would look like this:

```
newlist = oldlist[:index]
newlist.extend(oldlist[index + 1:])
```

You could do this latter version in one line using the `+` operator to merge the two slices, but using two lines and calling `extend` avoids an unnecessary extra copy of the first slice of values.

Note that unless `index` is always close to the end of the list, all of these approaches are going to take `O(len(oldlist))` time to complete, so don't do this a frequently on a very long list if you care about performance.

In all of my examples I've used `oldlist` as the existing list's name. I strongly encourage you to avoid using `list` as a variable name in your code, since it will mask the builtin `list` type. That's usually not going to be a problem immediately (especially if the `list` variable is a local variable in a function), but it might cause very confusing bugs if you later edit the code and don't remember that `list` is a local variable in that specific place.